# How do I run a function in react native only after button click on a single function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

By using react native and php, I'm trying to build a login page, fetching data from mysql server, if its in, the screen will be redirected to another screen. I'm totally new in react, and I'm lost at setState, which run the login function every time I update the textinput. So everytime I type, the alert will appear until I finally managed to insert correct data into the fields. I only want the function to run once the button is clicked. How do I solve this?
Thanks.

Shown below is the code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ImageBackground, View, StyleSheet, Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function LoginScreen({navigation}) {

    const [employeeNo, setEmployeeNo] = useState('');
    const [employeePassword, setEmployeePassword] = useState('');

    const loginEmployee = () => {
        var empNo = employeeNo;
        var empPass = employeePassword;

        if(empNo.length==0 || empPass==0){
            alert("Please insert all required fields!")
        }else{
            var apiURL = "http://example.com/api/login.php";
            var headers = {
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application.json',
            };
            var data = {
                empNo: empNo,
                empPass: empPass
            };
            fetch(apiURL,
                {
                    method:'POST',
                    headers: headers,
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                })
            .then((response)=>response.json())
            .then((response)=>
            {
                if (response[0].isCorrect ==1){                   
                    navigation.navigate('Home');
                }else{
                    Alert.alert(
                        "Error","Invalid employeeNo / Password. Please try again!"
                    )
                }
            }
                )
            .catch((error)=>{
                alert("Error" + error);
            })
        }
    }
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ImageBackground
            source={require('../assets/log-bg.jpg')} 
            style={styles.image}>
                <Image
                source={require('../assets/logo.png')}
                style={styles.logo}
                />
                <Text style={styles.text}>Mobile Application</Text>
                <View style={styles.inputStack}>
                    <Text
                    style={styles.loginText}
                    >Please Sign in to Continue</Text>
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder="Employee No..."
                    keyboardType='numeric'
                    onChangeText={employeeNo=>setEmployeeNo(employeeNo)}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder="Password..."
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    onChangeText={employeePassword=>setEmployeePassword(employeePassword)}
                    />
                    <Text
                    style={styles.hyperlink}
                    >Doesn't have an account? Click here to register.</Text>
                    <Button title='Press' onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Home')}/>
                </View>
                <View style={ styles.bottomView} >
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={loginEmployee()}
                    style={styles.button}>
                        <Text style={styles.textStyle}
                        >LOGIN</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onPress={loginEmployee()}
```

This line is the problem, basically everytime the component update it will trigger your function.

Why ?

For exampel: you do with a .map() to display some content dynamically, you use `{this.state.data.map((item) => <span>{item.name}</span>)}`

In your view page you agree with me that you will see the names displaying right ?

Beceause you're executing this function, react reads it and execute it like you've asked.

Now concerning your button, you don't want to be executed all the time, just when it is press. To fix that you need to write like this:

```
onPress={() => loginEmployee()}
```

Or like joessel wrote it works fine too

```
onPress={loginEmployee}
```

Doing so, it won't trigger automatically, but only when the event is launched

Comment: Thanks for the answer. now I understand when we should add the () after a function.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={loginEmployee()} <--- Here
    style={styles.button}
>
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>LOGIN</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

You are calling loginEmployee at each re-render, what you want is to reference your function to be called only when the use click on the button:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={loginEmployee} <--- Just remove the paranthesis
    style={styles.button}
>
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>LOGIN</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I now know that adding () will call a function immediately.